# There's virtually no way a search engine can help me find similar links to "sitemanager.aspx" AFAIK

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, site-settings

Absolute plebe here.

When I looked up if it was possible to move/copy sites to another site, an answer here helped but led to another question.

The solution was to use "http://yoursite/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx"

AFAIK sitemanager.aspx is NOT in 'site settings' (settings.aspx) nor did I see that anywhere else.

Such a useful page like sitemanager isn't easy to find. I'm wondering if anyone has already collected all useful links like "/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx" so I can see what I'm missing out on because apparently I missing out on a lot.

Per my title, any combination of "sharepoint online layout links" or what have you does not give what I'm looking for since "layout", "links", etc are it's own topics.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well that was quick. Guess I wasn't trying hard enough/was impatient

From 2013
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/how24/2013/05/23/famous-sharepoint-urls-locations/

From 2016
https://www.concurrency.com/blog/april-2016/helpful-sharepoint-urls